# length of checked checkbox is not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am having 4 checkbox on click of checkbox named chekcAll i want to check other 3 checkbox.

I am able to do it but I want to know how many checkbox are selected on that page.

I am using             $("input :checked").length

to find count of selected  checkbox.

But this is not working.

```
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
     if($("#checkAll").is(":checked")){
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).attr('checked',this.checked);
        alert($("input :checked").length);
     }
     else{
         $("input :checkbox").prop("checked",false);
         $("input :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7mx4k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `space` from `$("input :checked").length` like,

And try this,

```
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
  alert($("input:checked").length);     
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7mx4k/2/)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7mx4k/1/)

Their shoul be no space between

```
  alert($("input:checked").length);
```

Modify your code to get correct length by applying class ,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7mx4k/3/)

```
        <input type="checkbox" class="ckh_bx" id="checkItem">Item 1
        <input type="checkbox" class="ckh_bx" id="checkItem">Item 2
        <input type="checkbox" class="ckh_bx" id="checkItem">Item3
```

javascript code

```
         $("#checkAll").click(function () {
             if($("#checkAll").is(":checked")){
             $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
             $('input:checkbox').not(this).attr('checked',this.checked);
                 alert($(".ckh_bx:checked").length);
             }
             else{
                 $("input :checkbox").prop("checked",false);
                 $("input :checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
alert($("input:checkbox:checked").not(this).length);
```

ex:

```
var $checks = $('input:checkbox').not('#checkAll');
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
    $checks.prop('checked', this.checked);
    alert($checks.filter(':checked').length);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fuHc2/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in your alert selector which implies look for descendent of input

Should be

```
$("input:checked")
```

Similar problem within the `else` selectors

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

In this example you don´t have a whitespace between your selectors. 
This link should help you.